# Obtain iOS build number with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

In iOS settings -> General -> About -> Version is shown the current iOS version (e.g. 10.3.3) but there is also a build number (e.g. 14G60).

Like this one:
[image]

Is there a way to get this build number with Swift 4?

Thanks

Comment: can you be please more specific, like kind of screenshot or something like that.

Comment: @Deepraj Chowrasia, I added a screenshot. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Objective-C how do you get the BuildID of device programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884444/in-objective-c-how-do-you-get-the-buildid-of-device-programatically)